Update created engine in sqlacemy
I've created database using the following code:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

db_user = 'postgres'
db_password = 'chnageme'
db_host = '12.123.123.123'
db_port = '5432'
db_name = 'new_db'
# Create a connection string to connect to the PostgreSQL server
connection_string = f'postgresql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/'

# Create an SQLAlchemy engine
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

# Check if the database exists and create it if it doesn't
with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(text("SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = :db_name"), {"db_name": db_name})
    if not result.fetchone():
        connection.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE \"{db_name}\";")
        print(f"Database '{db_name}' created successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Database '{db_name}' already exists.")

engine = create_engine(f'{connection_string}{db_name}')

Now I'm wondering if there is an option\function to update original engine :
 engine = create_engine(connection_string)

Instead of creating new one later on?
engine = create_engine(rf'{connection_string}{db_name}')


If you want to connect to a different database you should create a new engine.
